# Why are Date treated like string with + and like number for any other arithmetic operators?

Tags: javascript, date

From my understanding if an object has `valueOf` function it will be used when object needs to be converted into a primitive. If an object has `toString` function it will be used when object needs to be converted into a string. So when you use `+` it should first use `valueOf` if present and then `toString`.

That's what it seems to do from :

```
var obj1 = {
  valueOf: () => 0
};

var obj2 = {
  toString: () => 'a'
};

var obj3 = { 
  valueOf: () => 0,
  toString: () => 'a'
};

obj1 + obj1; // -> 0
obj2 + obj2; // -> 'aa'
obj3 + obj3; // -> 0
```

Now Date is implementing both `valueOf` and `toString` like `obj3` but when you do `date + date` you get a string !
Using any other arithmetic operators will treat date as a number do the operation and return a valid number.

Here is some code to demonstrate my confusion :

```
var date = new Date(2017,1,1);

date - date; // -> 0
date * date: // -> 2.20790950849296e+24
date / date; // -> 1
date % date; // -> 0
date + date; // -> "Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```

Comment: The `valueOf`/`toString` preference is only for standard objects, dates are an exception unfortunately. And of course this is even more confusing with `+`, which doesn't know whether it should cast its arguments to numbers or to strings.

Comment: The behaviour goes back to [*ToPrimitive*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-toprimitive), for which the default hint is Number for all built-ins except Date and Symbol. Host objects may also use a different hint. It would be restrictive if the hint was always number, and string makes sense for dates given you may want to write `'Today is ' + new Date()`.

Comment: Both string and number make sense from an user point of view. You could also want to do `new Date() + 1000`. But what should have vouched for number is the consistency with other arithmetic operators. That's why I found it weird that string won that battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Date` has an exotic `@@toPrimitive` which prefers string over number. See [#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive)

> Date objects, are unique among built-in ECMAScript object in that they
>   treat "default" as being equivalent to "string", All other built-in
>   ECMAScript objects treat "default" as being equivalent to "number".

Comment: Any rational reason for that exotic behavior ?

Comment: You are writing in javascript and wonder about irregular, counter-intuitive behavior? I don't know what the people deciding this were thinking, but it's likely some legacy reason that now is never changed for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: The fact that Date is "unique" isn't exceptional. Symbol objects are also unique in that the hint is ignored. The comment about Date just points out its difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator will act as a concatenator in JS if the first operand is a string.  Since `date` yields a string, it will act as a concatenator in this case.

Comment: "*Since date yields a string*" - but why does it? `date.valueOf()` yields a number.

Answer (score 0):

An Object can be converted to a primitive value with the help of the **Symbol.toPrimitive** property (used as a function value).

> The function is called with a string argument **hint**, which specifies the preferred type of the result primitive value. The hint argument can be one of "number", "string", and "default".

**Syntax for Date objects** : `Date()[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint);`

> If hint is "string" or "default", @@toPrimitive tries to call the toString method. If the toString property does not exist, it tries to call the valueOf method and if the valueOf does not exist either, @@toPrimitive throws a TypeError.
>
> If hint is "number", @@toPrimitive first tries to call valueOf, and if that fails, it calls toString.

```js
var date = new Date(2017,1,1);

console.log('hint is "number":',+date + +date); // using unary plus operator
console.log('hint is "default":',date + date); // no hint (falls to hint == 'string')
console.log('hint is "string":',`${date + date}`); // using template literals
```

The `+` operator is the most confusing among all arithmetic operators. without a **hint** to convert the Date instance to a number, it acts as a string concatenator

Comment: The the question becomes why is default hint string and not number ?

Comment: let's say the default is number. Then the question becomes why is default hint number and not string :) I hope you see where I'm going... default string  for dates is much more convenient/practical, you can format it and display it the way you want. (you can say it's a conceptual choice)

Comment: Maybe it's opinion based then but it seems to me being a number is way more logical and practical. A date is just a number and it's evaluate as a number for all arithmetic operators **except** for +.

Comment: respectful point of view. But we have to make our peace with what we got ^^

Comment: @Ghetolay—other arithmetic operators only do mathematics, but `+` is overloaded so there needs to be a choice between converting to number or string. From my point of view, converting Date to string makes a lot of sense. I think `startDate + endDate` is pretty rare, but `'Start date: ' + startDate` is pretty common (or would be if you could easily specify the output format, but that's another story…).